# Hygen template generator converting quotes to &#39;

Tags: node.js, generator, code-generation

I am using Hygen to populate template files and want to print an array of strings eg.

`` [`'${item}'`] ``

but the single quotes are being converted to `&#39;`

All other special characters are unaffected but single or doublequotes get converted so I'm not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out

> <%= %>

tags in the template file escapes some characters, whereas...

> <%- %>

does not!